# Ruby on Rails installation error: Could not locate Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am new to Ruby on Rails, Now try to install ROR. I follow this tutorials `http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/10/27/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-in-ubuntu-11-10/`

After install this `gem install rails` create my project like `rails new myproject`.
here showing this message

`Your bundle is complete! Use`bundle show [gemname]`to see where a bundled gem is installed.` .

After then i run `bundle install` its showing this error `Could not locate Gemfile`.

please help me how can i solve this problem.

Comment: Have you a Gmefile in your myproject directory ? Have you launch this command from your myproject directory ?

Comment: I run this command inside my project directory then its showing this message=> Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you are in the project directory before running `bundle install`.

For example, after running `rails new myproject`, you will need to `cd myproject` before running `bundle install`.

Comment: When i run this command "rails new myproject" its showing this message "Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed."

Comment: What is your Rails version ? The Gemfile is automaticaly generated since Rails 3.x.